# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty }(\frac{n^{2}+1}{n-1})^{-2n^{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> How to evaluate the following limit?
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty }(\frac{n^{2}+1}{n-1})^{-2n^{2}}
> $$

I have tried the following:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\frac{n^{2}+1+2n-2n}{n-1})^{-2n^{2}} 
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{(n-1)^{2}+2n}{n-1})^{-2n^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{(n-1)^{2}}{n-1}+\frac{2n}{n-1})^{-2n^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty }({n-1}+\frac{2n}{n-1})^{-2n^{2}}
\end{align}
$$

I know that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e
$$
But I can't come to that form in my equation.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{n^2+1}{n-1}\right)^{-2n^2}=\dfrac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n+1+\dfrac2{n-1}\right)^{2n^2}}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$\left(\frac{n^{2}+1}{n-1}\right)^{-2n^{2}}=\left(\frac{n-1}{n^{2}+1}\right)^{2n^{2}}<\left(\frac1n\right)^{2n^2}\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\left(\frac{n^{2}+1}{n-1}\right)^{-2n^{2}}=n^{-2n^2}\left(\frac{n+\frac1n}{n-1}\right)^{-2n^{2}}=n^{-2n^2}\left(\frac{n-1+1+\frac1n}{n-1}\right)^{-2n^{2}}=$$

$$=n^{-2n^2}\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n(n-1)}\right)^{-2n^{2}}=n^{-2n^2}\left[\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n(n-1)}\right)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{n+1}}\right]^{\frac{-2n^{2}(n+1)}{n(n-1)}}=$$$$=\frac1{n^{2n^2}\left[\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n(n-1)}\right)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{n+1}}\right]^{\frac{2n^{2}(n+1)}{n(n-1)}}}\sim \frac{1}{n^{2n^2}e^{2n}}$$

Comment: Great solution, thank you very much.

Comment: @violettagold It can be simplified a lot, I did in that way in order to use the knwn limit for $e$ but it is not necessary of course.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed. I had simplified my answer at the end.